# mysql doesn't update information from html/php

Tags: php, html, mysql, insert

The problem I have: I made a "contact" form, which should send data to my database. All works good, no errors after I access the page from localhost, shows the result I wanted to see, but the database (localhost/phpmyadmin/..) doesn't update with any info.

This is my PHP:

```
 if(isset($_POST['insert']))
{
    $hostname = 'localhost';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $databaseName = 'nig';

$Nume = $_POST['nume'];
$Email = $_POST['email'];
$Telefon = $_POST['telefon'];
$Subiect = $_POST['subiect'];
$Mesaj = $_POST['mesaj'];

$connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);
$query = "INSERT INTO `amar` (`nume`, `email`, `telefon`, `subiect`, `mesaj`) VALUES ('$Nume','$Email','$Telefon','$Subiect','$Mesaj')";

$result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);

if($result)
{
    echo 'Mesaj trimis.';
}else{
    echo 'Mesaj netrimis';
}

mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($connect);
```

This is my HTML:

```
<form action="insert2.php" action="post">
    <form role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nume">Nume complet</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="nume">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Adresa e-mail</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="telefon">Telefon</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="telefon">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="subiect">Subiect</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="subiect">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="mesaj">Mesaj</label>
        <textarea class="form-control"  name="mesaj" rows="8"></textarea>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" name="insert" class="btn btn-theme" value="insert"></button>
    </form>
```

And the result should be data in my MySQL. but the database isn't getting any data, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: ??? Second form tag??? `<form role="form">` Remove it

Comment: Parameterize your queries. This is open to SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

You have two form tags, one inside the other.

Change this....

```
<form action="insert2.php" action="post">
<form role="form">
```

To this...

```
<form action="insert2.php" action="post">
```

Also, please note, your PHP code is open to SQL injection. Never trust user input. Always validate and/or escape user entered data prior to using it in a query. Or better yet, used [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or stored procedures.

**Update 1:**

OK, sorry to hear this is not working. Please add the following [mysqli error debugging](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) so we can see what is happening.

Change this...

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
```

To this...

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$result = mysqli_query($connect,$query)

if (!$result)) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($connect));
}
```

Then run the code and see if you get any errors that may help us.

**Update 2:**

OK, try another piece of debugging.

After this...

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `amar` (`nume`, `email`, `telefon`, `subiect`, `mesaj`) VALUES ('$Nume','$Email','$Telefon','$Subiect','$Mesaj')";
```

Add this...

```
die($query);
```

Save and run the code.

You will be given a SQL query. Copy and paste that SQL query and run it in your database management tool (phpMyAdmin for example). See if the record is added when you manually run the query or if you are given any errors.

Let us know the outcome.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm a beginner. about the exposure, I have some code to paste it, written to prevent that. But this is my #10 try to put the data into the database, I did edit how you said but it's still not working.

Comment: I did put the code in it (without error, after many tries) , but no error is showing up. My db has (ID-ai., Nume, Email, Telefon, Subiect, Mesaj). And the db is named nig, table named amar. These known, is the code right? Because syntax is shown as correct and the result page after hitting insert is the right one with no anomalies on it. Only the db isn't updating the info

Comment: @danut Ok, I have edited the answer with a further instruction.

Comment: WebCode.ie, I want to thank you for your support, but this is out of my knowledge  and I'm sure that I don't know something that is very important, that's stopping me from getting my wanted result. I'll try in the morning to fix it with whatever tutorials I find online, or to write another way to acces the database, but I get frustrated when I spend many hours and it doesn't work. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @danut OK, thats a shame! Good luck with it.